# How to change password?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-authentication

I want to edit form update only `address`, `email` and `password`. How to change password? The old password is important.

**edit.blade.php**

```php
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('update') }}">
    @csrf
    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-1 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Email') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') ? : user()->email }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

            @error('email')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-1 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input id="password" type="text" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" value="{{ old('password') }}" required autocomplete="password" autofocus>

            @error('password')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="address" class="col-md-1 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Address') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-5">
            <textarea id="address" type="text" class="form-control @error('address') is-invalid @enderror" name="address" required autocomplete="address" autofocus>{{ old('address') ? : user()->address }}</textarea>

            @error('address')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
                {{ __('Register') }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Route**

```php
Route::post('update', 'Auth\RegisterController@sqlupdate')->name('update');
```

**RegisterController**

```php
public function sqlupdate(Request $request)
{
    Auth::user()->update([
        'address' => $request['address'],
        'email' => $request['email'],
    ]);

    $hashedPassword = auth()->user()->password;
    if (Hash::check($request->oldpassword, $hashedPassword)){
        $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::id());
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with: Old password is important?

Comment: I mean, certainly the old password should be in my code.

Comment: You don't update old password, you just don't fill the password field while updating profile, now if you want to update old password just fill the password field.

Comment: @ViperTecPro Yes I want this

Comment: Try to just put this `if($request->password !== null)`

Comment: I tried it , but I did not solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the below code carefully :-

```
/**
 * Admin My profile : Password update.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function updatePassword(Request $request,$id = 0)
{
    $validate = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'old_password'          => 'required',
        'password'              => 'required|confirmed|min:8',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:8',
        ]);
    $getUserData = Admin::where('id',$id)->first();
    if($getUserData === null) {
        return  redirect()->back()->with([
            'status'    => 'warning',
            'title'     => 'Warning!!',
            'message'   => 'Invalid Admin ID.'
            ]);
    }
    $validate->after(function ($validate) use ($request,$getUserData,$id) {
       if(!Hash::check($request->get('old_password'),$getUserData->password)){
           $validate->errors()->add('old_password', 'Wrong old password');
       }
   });
    if($validate->fails()){
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validate)->withInput();
    }
    try{
        $getUserData->update([
            'password'  => Hash::make($request->get('password'))
            ]);
        return  redirect()->back()->with([
            'status'    => 'success',
            'title'     => 'Success!!',
            'message'   => 'Admin password updated successfully.'
            ]);
    }catch (Exception $e){
        return  redirect()->back()->with([
            'status'    => 'error',
            'title'     => 'Error!!',
            'message'   => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
    }
}
```

With the above method you'll get the idea of how we update password, this is from one of my project i've created three field for that here is the screenshot of view :-
[image]

I hope this will help

> Further more update here is the small snippet for update method
>   specially

```
 $getOldPassword = User::where('id',$id)->first();
 if($request->get('password') === null){
     $password = $getOldPassword->password;
 }else{
     $password = Hash::make($request->get('password'));
 }
```